# Local images in HTML

Tags: html, image

I'm an high school student and I'm working on something for fun. I've linked a local file stored on my computer to my webpage. What can I do to make it possible for other devices to access the local html file? (meme1.html)

```
<div id="button">
<a href="C:\Users\Desktop\MEME GENERATOR\meme1.html">
<img src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/140365/1306313012.png" alt="Click here!" height="20%" width="20%"></a>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<h1><span class="tight-2">Happy Birthday!</h1>
<h2>Go ahead, press the button to generate memes!<span class="tm">™</span>.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with _other devices to access the local html file_?

Comment: please be more specific. Do you want to access the webpage which is running on your computer on other devices?

Comment: You need to install a webserver (how & which will depend on your OS) and install the file(s) into a hosted folder; or else create an account (free or paid) at a web hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, when you host the site online you have to change the linked file path to the one of the server instead of your local machine.

Edit: If youre using plain HTML my answer stands, if you use a backend platform like Django, Flask or dotNet Core then the urls are dynamicly stated in your webapp.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean? That you want other people to access your website?
Few ways to do that.

- One thing you could do is to send the whole directory to the individual to who you want to send the webpage to.
- Or the other way is what you can do is host the webpage on a hosting website. There are a lot of hosting websites that would host your websites for free.

That way anyone with a given URL can access the website.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the local file is only available to the system it resides on. For instance this link you've created:
`<a href="C:\Users\Desktop\MEME GENERATOR\meme1.html">`
is telling the browser to look in the C: drive of the machine it's currently installed on. Every other system in your network (and the world, for that matter) will likely not be to pull that file because MEME GENERATOR isn't a folder on their system, so they will see a 404 (file not found) error.

That said, you can load links within your network by using network addresses. This will be the machine's network IP address, typically starting with 192.168.

That said, in order to load the file, the machine that it is running on will need to have a port open for the client machine's browser to connect to. This is typically port 80, unless SSL is in use, in which case it's typically port 8080, for HTTP traffic.

In doing so, the computer that is serving up the files becomes, logically, a 'server'. And this is the core of the client (user) to server relationship that the whole of the internet and networking is built upon.

Since you're on Windows, you can use something like XAMPP or WAMP to run a server locally that will have Apache installed, which can serve files through these ports. You're going to need to read up on these technologies a lot to get a file going, and be forewarned that this will open your system to hacking and the like.

EDIT: rereading your question, you are maybe trying to get this file to load on your website? If this is the case, then you need to upload the file to your website, and then it will have a folder structure similar to a local Windows file. [YOUR.DOMAIN.COM]/[whatever folder you create on your server in the public directory]/meme1.html